# How flex: 100% works in css?

Tags: css, flexbox, specifications

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#constituent_properties) web docs states : "flex property is a shorthand for the "flex-grow", "flex-shrink", "flex-basis".

> One-value syntax: the value must be one of:
>
> a `<number>`: In this case it is interpreted as flex: `<number> 1 0`;
> the "flex-shrink" value is assumed to be 1 and the "flex-basis" value
> is assumed to be 0.

[Here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_responsive2) of w3school which controls the container's layout by putting `flex: 50%` and `flex: 100%` to the child columns after affecting the media query.

It's obvious that this `100%` is not for `flex-growing`, it's used as `flex-basis`. But how is that possible? If there is single value, It should be assumed for `flex-grow`.

Am I missing something here? Is that because of `%` that causes to be counted for `flex-basis`?

Comment: Because 100% **is not a number** it's a percentage so it's ignored for flex-grow and flex-shrink.

Comment: 100% is not  a number so that rule won't apply

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks I should've guessed that. Is it a general rule for other shortcut syntaxes ? If the first one doesn't satisfy the condition, it will be checked for next ones...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your refer to [the Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) you can read:

> Value: `none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]`

The `||` means:

> A double bar (`||`) separates two or more options: **one or more of them must occur**, in any order.

If you specify a percetange value it's clearly not `<'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>?` so it's `<'flex-basis'>`

If you specify a number then it cannot be `<'flex-basis'>` because it doesn't accept `number` so it will be `<'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>?` and the `?` means:

> A question mark (`?`) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group **is optional** (occurs zero or one times).

So it's `<'flex-grow'>`

---

Here is more combinations:

```
flex: 1 1 --> <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>

flex: 1 50% 
  1   -->  <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? --> <'flex-grow'>
  50% --> <'flex-basis'>
```

Comment: Also, although we're used to seeing this format: `flex: 1 1 50%`, per the rule above, it can also be expressed as `flex: 50% 1 1`.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin yes, due to the *any order* of the `||`